# Uploading doesn't work on MKR1000

Tags: error, upload

I received the error bellow when I tried to upload any sketch on my MKR100. I uninstall/reinstall de COM drivers and the arduino IDE and nothing solve the problem. I bought another MKR1000 thinking the ahrdare was the problem , but I got the same errors.
Also If I try to open the serial monitor I got :
Error opening serial port 'ÇOM12'(Port not found)

Can someone help me?

Sketch uses 47444 bytes (18%) of program storage space. Maximum is 262144 bytes.
Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port COM12
processing.app.debug.RunnerException
at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:152)
at cc.arduino.UploaderUtils.upload(UploaderUtils.java:77)
at processing.app.SketchController.upload(SketchController.java:732)
at processing.app.SketchController.exportApplet(SketchController.java:703)
at processing.app.Editor$UploadHandler.run(Editor.java:2055)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: processing.app.SerialException: Error touching serial port 'COM12'.
at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:107)
at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:136)
... 5 more
Caused by: jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - COM12; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port not found.
at jssc.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:167)
at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:101)
... 6 more

Comment: did you select the correct port?

Comment: Thank for you answer. No, the IDE can find the board and port but I got those errs anyway.

Comment: read the answer, not the question. did you try the double reset mentioned in the answer?

Comment: I'm sorry my mistake, I tried the double tap on reset button and it works!!. Thanks for your help.